# Идентификация клиента в JS (безопасность)

Tags: javascript

Как можно идентифицировать клиента на сервере?

Допустим:
10000 человек пользуются услугами оператора по предоставлению связи в локальной и интернет сети.

---

**У каждого человека из этой сети, есть:**

*внешний динамический IP(может быть одинаковый для пользователей сети)* **и** *внутренний статический IP.*

**Для каждого человека, аккаунт на сервере(сервер находится в интернете),** должен создаваться автоматически (логин и пароль генерируются сервером)

---

если использовать разные виды хранилищ(локалсторадже, куки, хранилищефлеш и.т.д) для хранения уникальных **ид**, которые можно присылать на клиент с сервера, то с одного внутреннего ип, можно будет хоть сколько угодно аккаунтов сделать (1000, 100000 или больше) за минимальное количество времени.

Вопрос: Как идентифицировать человека на сервере, с тем учётом что может использоваться любое устройство (мобильные, планшеты, компьютеры, нуотбуки)?

Comment: @Igor what?.?.?

Comment: А что, по ip идентифицировать не судьба

Comment: @Mike  Mike - нет, написано что ип у них динамический, а это значит что у них ип внешний, может быть одинаковый.

Comment: @Mike сейчас отредактирую вопрос. это плохо..... если все 1000 человек-роботов(ботов) зайдут одновременно, то система может подумать что совершилась атака и заблокирует для всех доступ. эх.... ниужеле нету никакого выхода?

Comment: Для этого собственно и используют капчи и самостоятельную регистрацию. А без регистрации вы человека никак не идтетифицируете. Он же может зайти на сервер с компа, который через домашний интернет подключен и одновременно с мобильного, подключенного через сотового оператора ...

Comment: @Mike да, но тут капчу использовать не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Против обычных пользователей достаточно куки.
Против тех, кто **хочет** накрутить акков ничего не спасёт.
Или статичный `IP` менять нельзя никак? Но достать его из-за `NAT` трудно, даже невозможно бывает.

Концентрируйтесь на отлове акков без активности, ограничение по времени для регистрации с одного IP и прочих плюшек, которых довольно много в сети.

Comment: это есть интересный вариант и в разработанной мной архитектуре его предполагалось задействовать. Похоже это единственный способ идентификации. Эх...

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, такова судьба :)

Answer (score 2):

Погуглите это

> X-Client-IP

и особенно это

> X-Forwarded-For

В вопросе не разбираюсь но `X-Forwarded-For` когда-то мне встречался.

Comment: Мало кто из провайдеров использует прокси которые ставят эти поля. Обычно провайдеры используют маскарад который по определению данные в пакетах не меняет и заголовки не добавляет

Comment: Извините тогда, наверное только мой и использует.